# Android how to set date and calendar objects from string

Tags: android, date, calendar, format

i have a string with a date in this format yyyyMMddHHmmss, so i want to know how to set a Date object and a Calendar object in android.

For example if my string date is 20120215102400 how i make a function that returns a Calendar object with that date, and also how i make a function that returns a Date object. Maybe is a easy one but i still learning android and java too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String mytime="20120215102400";
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyyMMddhhmmss");

        try {
            Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(mytime);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Correct date format string is: "yyyyMMddhhmmss". Capital "MM" for month.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this will help you to get Date.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Getting calendar is trivial afterwards